# Label updating during audio processing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, uilabel

I'm very new to ios programming and I'm facing a problem regarding the update of labels during  audio processing tasks.

I use a classic RecordingCallback -> ProcessAudio method. In ProcessAudio I would like to stop the recording if the level is too low. This was quite easy to do. But when it stops, I can't change the text label from "Recording" to "Stopped". It works great with the button (play/stop) but not when calling back. There is no error during compiling. Just nothing happens...

Here is the code :

```
-(void)processAudio:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList{
AudioBuffer sourceBuffer = bufferList->mBuffers[0];

// copy incoming audio data to temporary buffer
memcpy(tempBuffer.mData, bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

int16_t* samples = (int16_t*)(tempBuffer.mData);

for ( int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.mDataByteSize / 2; ++i )
{
    if (samples[i]< LevelTrigger) 
    {
        Presence++;
        if (Presence== 2 * SampleRate) 
        {
            printf("Nothing");
            //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self buttonPressed:nil];
            //});
            //[self buttonPressed:nil];
            [label performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"TEST" waitUntilDone:YES];
            Presence=0;
            break;

        }
  }
```

As you can see, I have tried to use "dispatch_async" and "performSelectorOnMainThread" functions but it didn't help. The buttonPressed function is called correctly, but nothing happens.
Thanks for you help.
JC

Comment: Interesting - can't see anything obvious. Can you please share something compilable for reproducing the effect? (E.g. github.com , bitbucket.org, pastebin.com)

Comment: If tour `buttonPressed` method get called properly, why don't you move the label.text there an you can send the text as parameter to your method, but you have to check the type of your param, in case you are doing other things with it.

Comment: @Christoph I'm sorry but it is a professional app, so it is confidential... Thank you.

Comment: @danypata I have already tried this, with no success.

Comment: I bet label is nil. Otherwise try calling a method without passing the NSString object. I.e., a method that just sets the text to some hardcoded value

Comment: @jcr Can you maybe strip it down to HelloWorld + something reproducing your problem?

Comment: Sure. For example, you can try with the riograph code. it doesn't work. [link](https://github.com/jar-son/rioGraph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

1. Cloned the repository provided by your link:
   `git clone https://github.com/jar-son/rioGraph.git`
2. Can you read patch format? http://pastebin.com/Sc0eb3tR (link is valid for 30 days from now on)
    Summary of what I did:

   - Added a `@class ViewController` to Audio.h
   - Added a `@property (nonatomic, assign) ViewController *viewController;` to the Audio.h
   - Added `[self.viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setMyLabel) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];`
      to 
     `-(void)processAudio:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList` in Audio.m
   - Added `- (void)setMyLabel;` to ViewController.h
   - Added
     `- (void)setMyLabel
     {
         self.label.text = @"blablabla!";
     }` to ViewController.m
3. ...and it just worked.

PS: This explains how to apply a patch: https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much Christophe !

Comment: Oops sorry - I'm French :)